# Python: about [:] and its behavior in a function

Tags: function, pass-by-reference, list-comprehension

```
def call(nums):
    nums[:] = [x for x in nums if x != 4]

numbers = [4, 5]
print(numbers)
call(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

The output for the above code is:

```
[4, 5]
[5]
```

But if you remove the "[:]", the output becomes the following:

```
[4, 5]
[4, 5]
```

I know that `[:]` makes a copy of the full list, but why the function argument is modified in one case and not in the other?

Answer (score 0):

As Python passes objects by reference, when you execute your function with `nums[:] = ...` line, you change actual list that you've passed from outside, `numbers`. When you change line to `nums = ...`, you just overwrite local variable called `nums`, without affecting `numbers` array.

---

In Python, you can not only slice collections to read them, but you can assign to slices, replacing sliced content.

For example:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[1:4]
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you assign to slice, it will replace part of original array:

```
>>> a[1:4] = ['z']
>>> a
[0, 'z', 4, 5]
```

But when assigning to slices, array remains the same:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = a
>>> a[:] = ['z']
>>> a
['z']
>>> b
['z']
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` change at the same time, because when assigning to slice, you don't change object's identity, you only change its contents.

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = a
>>> a = ['z']
>>> a
['z']
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This is not the case when you just assign to variable, dropping older array out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected the issue is hiding in the slicer in line:

```
nums[:] = [x for x in nums if x != 4]
```

Python is "pass by value" which means that you're not passing the pointer `numbers` into the function, but a copy of it. So re-assigning a value to a copy of the reference will not change the original reference.

But, when you use the slicer, you're accessing the object behind the reference and changing it *directly* which is why you see the side effect *after* you exit the function - when using the "slice".

Answer (score 0):

```
def call(nums):
    nums = [x for x in nums if x != 4]
```

Would only change the value of the name `nums` function parameter which would accomplish nothing.

```
def call(nums):
    nums[:] = [x for x in nums if x != 4]
```

Changes the actual value of the list passed in as an argument.